# Games Deleted Everytime I Restart Computer

Tags: dual-boot, games, memory-usage, reinstall

I dual booted my pc and have added games onto Ubuntu, however whenever I turn off my computer, the games require me to reinstall them entirely, resulting in lost memory although the game still shows as being downloaded. No idea what to do from this point other than just delete the duplicated game and reinstall every time.

Comment: Please tell us how you are dual booting! It seems to me that you are running a live session, 'Try Ubuntu'.

Comment: It is a full installation

Comment: OK. Normally, a program should not need reinstalling. I know very little about games, but I can ask you to *tell us about the games:* which games, how are they installed? Is there some setting that controls if the installation is persistent?

Comment: I partitioned my drives but the issue may be here: When trying to download games on steam it gave me 2 options for drives to install to which were: 
Create new Steam Library on Drive /
Create new Steam Library on Drive /boot/efi 

I chose the first one then I think put them somewhere along the lines of home/local/share/steam/steamapps/

Comment: Games are CS, Rocket League, Just Cause 3

Comment: Are you by any chance logging in as Guest?

Comment: Nope, however I found the problem on another forum and apparently just resetting steam fixed it. All good now, thank you for your contribution.